# Generating getters and setters for entities out of a bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I created my models in ORM-Designer and changed doctrine config file to know about my application structure that is in following format

```
-app
-src
   -Acme
     - Model
        - Model_1.php
        - Model_2.php
        - ...
     - ApplicationBundle
- ...
```

Doctrine config:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        # auto_mapping: true

        mappings:
            model:
                type: yml
                dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/Model
                prefix: Acme\Model
                alias: Model
                is_bundle: false
```

Model_1.php for example:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Model;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/** 
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Model_1
{
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $attribute_01;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $attribute_02;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $attribute_03;
}
```

as you see my `Model` is not a bundle and when I try to use `doctrine:generate:entities Acme` command to set missing `getters` and `setters` it throws following exception:

```
[RuntimeExeption] Namespace "Acme" does not contain any mapped entities.
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried "Acme\\Model" or "Model" (alias)? "Acme" is not a namespace of you entities.

Comment: yep I tried Acme, Acme\Model, Model but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `dir` without the prefix, i.e. `%kernel.root_dir%/../src`. I tried something similar once for a project and had the same problem. I recall that it was some problem with how Doctrine is looking for the files. I try to find the code and post a more conclusive answer if I still have it laying around